# RSA KeyPairGenerator with BouncyCastleProvider e*d(φ(n)) not equal to one

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle, key-pair

I used BouncyCastleProvider(version is 1.54) to generate RSA keypair, and I want to test if the key is valid. According to wikipedia the RSA algorithm key as below:

1. Choose two distinct prime numbers p and q
2. Compute n = pq
3. Compute φ(n) = φ(p)φ(q) = (p − 1)(q − 1) = n − (p + q − 1)
4. Choose an integer e such that 1 < e < φ(n) and gcd(e, φ(n)) = 1;
   i.e., e and φ(n) are coprime
5. Determine d as d ≡ e−1 (mod φ(n));This is more clearly stated as:
   solve for d given d⋅e ≡ 1 (mod φ(n))

Then I generate 1000 keypairs, which I found only about 30% keypairs fit with  d⋅e ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)). However,I got 100% d⋅e ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)) when I don't use BC provider. Is that something wrong with BC 1.54version?  And what's the problem if e*d(φ(n)) not equal to one. Can anybody help? Thanks a lot. and my test java code as below:

```
public void testRSAKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator rsa = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        rsa.initialize(1024,new SecureRandom());
        int total=0;
        int isOne=0,notOne=0;
        BigInteger one=  new BigInteger("1");
        while (total<1000) {
            KeyPair keyPair = rsa.generateKeyPair();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            BCRSAPrivateCrtKey privateCrtKey = (BCRSAPrivateCrtKey) privateKey;
            BigInteger primeP = privateCrtKey.getPrimeP();
            BigInteger primeQ = privateCrtKey.getPrimeQ();
            BigInteger p1 = primeP.add(new BigInteger("-1"));
            BigInteger q1 = primeQ.add(new BigInteger("-1"));
            BigInteger fn = p1.multiply(q1);
            BigInteger publicExponent = privateCrtKey.getPublicExponent();
            BigInteger privateExponent = privateCrtKey.getPrivateExponent();
            BigInteger mod = publicExponent.multiply(privateExponent).mod(fn);//mod  ought to be one
            if(mod.equals(one)) {
                System.out.println("e*d(mod fn)=" + mod);
                isOne++;
            }else {
                System.out.println("e*d(mod fn) not equal to one");
                notOne++;
            }
            total++;
        }
        System.out.println("total=" + total);
        System.out.println("isOne=" + isOne);
        System.out.println("notOne=" + notOne);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: if e*d(φ(n)) is not equal to one you cannot decrypt with the private exponent. So this means a major problem with the generated key. Maybe just the extraction of the key parameters has a problem (this is normally not needed) and it works for encrypt/decrypt cycles?

Comment: @Henry It workds fine, and actually  I found that φ(n) can equal to LCM(q-1,p-1), which would less than φ(p)φ(q), and the new version of BC use  λ(n)=lcm(p−1,q−1)λ(n)=lcm(p−1,q−1) instead of φ(n).

Comment: Ok, you need (a^e)^d == a (mod pq) and e * d==1 (mod (p-1)*(q-1)) is a sufficient condition for that, but actually if e * d==1 (mod  λ(n)) this works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found that BC may use λ(n)=lcm(p−1,q−1)λ(n)=lcm(p−1,q−1) instead of φ(n). and I change my code :

```
   BigInteger fn = (p1.multiply(q1)).divide(p1.gcd(q1));
```

And it works fine and all results are "e*d(mod fn)=1". Although I don't understant the the deepest of the theory now , the wikipedia's RSA algorithm is not the latest one maybe

Comment: When I ran your code against version 1.46 it didn't display the behaviour you documented. It seems to have changed in 1.47.